# How to use if/else in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Provider]
(@strPro varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * 
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1]
    WHERE [Name] = @strPro
END
```

I have a dropdownlist which will have the following entry:

```
All People
John D.
Mike K.
Alan H.
Paul Q.
```

How can I modify the stored procedure so that if the user selects `All People` the `WHERE` statement will be a `LIKE` instead of a `=` sign

Example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Provider]
(@strPro varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * 
    FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1]

    if @strPro = 'All People'
    BEGIN
        WHERE [Name] LIKE '%'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WHERE [Name] = @strPro
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, where you build the SQL statement in the Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Provider]
(
    @strPro varchar(200)
)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL varchar(2000)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1] '

    if @strPro <> 'All People'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE [Name] = ''' + @strPro + '''
    END

    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Note1: You won't need a WHERE clause if you want 'All People' ...
Note2: you may have to adjust some of the single quotes ...

Answer (score 7):

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1]
WHERE @strPro = 'All People' OR [Name] = @strPro
```

If "All People" is passed - first condition will be true and all records will be returned (You don't need to do `LIKE '%'`) otherwise only records with matched [Name] will be returned.

Comment: `All People` != `John D.`... for example. Sorry let me clarify, if `All People` is selected return all of the list not just `All People`.

Comment: I think you may have missed the explanation in the answer ... this will work the way it is described in the original question.

Comment: SearchForKnowledge - `[Name] LIKE '%'` is equivalent to `@strPro = 'All People'` in this case.  Both queries return all the rows when "All People" is selected.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Try it in action. See if it behaves as desired.

Comment: You know what, it is late in the day and my brain is fried... you are right :) It wasn't supposed to be rude although maybe it sounded like it. My apology.